# Show .bmp file in ImageView Android 6

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My application receives `ByteArray` with .bmp file in it from backend. I need to output that bmp file in ImageView. For Android versions 7+ I create `Bitmap` with `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` and then do `imgView.setImageBitmap()` and it works perfectly fine. But for OS versions 5 and 6 `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` returns `null`.

I also tried writing bytes to file and creating `Bitmap` from file or stream - no good. Creating `Drawable` from the file and using file's `Uri` for `ImageView.setImageUri()` didn't solve the issue either.

Picasso and Glide libraries also don't work.

I would think that Android 5 and 6 can't work with bmp at all, but that just doesn't sound right. Also when I put test image (the same as the one that I receive from server) to `res/mipmap` folder I am able to output it to my ImageView.

So my question is what is the solution to that? How do I output .bmp image from `ByteArray` or locally saved file to `ImageView` on Android 5 and 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the issue. There was a bug in my bitmap receiving code, so the final `ByteArray` didn't contain data for the last image column. Apparently, Android 7+ decoding mechanism ignores this issue and just decodes as much data as possible. But the previous versions of the OS strictly require enough data for full image.